# Enable hyphenated word breaking

Tags: line-breaking

When I compile my LaTeX file to produce pdf, the word breaking is not happening. Instead the complete word moves to the next line and extra spaces are inserted between the words in the current line. How can I enable this feature and have word breaks?

I've searched on google and this site. All questions and answers talk about the other-way-round problem i.e. word breaking is enabled and they want to disable that.

I'm using `pdflatex`.

Comment: Please provide the MWE.

Comment: what is the document class that you're using?

Comment: article - 10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper

Comment: You don't need to do anything special to have wordbreaks. So there is something special in your document, and no one here knows what you have in your document. So you have to show us an actual example (a complete document) where the problem can be seen to make it possible to help you. Keep it short! That is don't include your actual document but only two lines if you can make such a document that shows the problem.

Comment: Okay. I'll try to provide that. Thing is this is a conference template. So, I can't just provide a 2 line doc, right?

Comment: I tried the same document on another machine. There, I'm getting line breaks properly. So, I guess it's some settings in my PC. Even if I provide a MWE, it will work on your PC. Right? Do you still think I should provide a MWE?

Comment: If you get a problem only in one environment then it sounds like something is wrong with that environment. Don't you get any error messages or warning messages when you run LaTeX on this document in that environment?

Comment: I've got 2 warnings: `LaTeX Warning: You have requested package 'eso-pic', but the package provides 'everyshi'.` and `Package hyperref Warning: Option 'letterpaper' is no longer used.` Any idea if any of these is causing the problem?

Comment: Probably not.  It sounds like the cause of your problem is that you haven't loaded the correct hyphenation patterns in your format.  Which language is your document in, can you find it in your system's `language.dat` (`kpsewhich language.dat` on the command line)?

Comment: The result is as follows: `$ kpsewhich language.dat
/var/lib/texmf/tex/generic/config/language.dat`